# strace of wget gives strange socket call

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu, wget, strace

"strace wget grooveshark.com" stops with strange socket calls with wrong string length and I have to Ctrl+C to terminate.

```
write(2, "Connecting to grooveshark.com (g"..., 67Connecting to grooveshark.com (grooveshark.com)|8.20.213.76|:80... ) = 67
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("8.20.213.76")}, 16) = 0
write(2, "connected.\n", 11connected.
)            = 11
select(4, NULL, [3], NULL, {900, 0})    = 1 (out [3], left {899, 999993})
write(3, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Wget"..., 115) = 115
write(2, "HTTP request sent, awaiting resp"..., 40HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ) = 40 [[ Check this line ]]
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {900, 0} ^C
```

write(2, "HTTP request sent, awaiting resp"..., 40HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ) = 40

should be

write(2, "HTTP request sent, awaiting response...", 40 ) = 40

but strace wget google.com gives

```
write(3, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Wget"..., 116) = 116
write(2, "HTTP request sent, awaiting resp"..., 40) = 40
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {900, 0})    = 1 (in [3], left {899, 932611})
```

and properly terminates.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing the output of wget mixed with the output of strace. Use the -o option of `strace` to store the trace in a file so that this won't happen.

> write(2, "HTTP request sent, awaiting resp"..., 40HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ) = 40

This write call in wget prints the message to stderr, and before it returns, its output is seen in the terminal, between 40 and the closing parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

By default `strace` is outputting on *stderr* which is usually your terminal window. So the trace given by `strace` is mixed with the output of the traced program.

You could run `strace -o /tmp/wget.tr wget http://grooveshark.com/` to get the trace in file `/tmp/wget.tr` (and you could run simultanously `tail -f /tmp/wget.tr` in another terminal to look inside).

I suggest to read carefully the output of [man strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).